# Using a PreferenceActivity to let the user pick something from a lsit

Tags: android

I have created an activity which when launched, displays a list of items, allowing the user to create, rename, delete, etc. items from this list. Once the user clicks an item on the list, the activity calls `setResult()` followed by `finish()`. I use this activity various times in my application, and want to use it to let the user select a default value from this list from a PreferenceActivity. So basically, I want it to flow like this:

1. User goes into the app's preferences
2. User selects the button to change the default item
3. My activity launches, and the user selects an item from that list
4. My activity finishes, having set the result
5. The value the user selected is now saved as the default value as a preference in the application

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `ListPreference` inside the Preference Activity. Maybe add an `EditTextPreference` if they want to insert their own custom item. An activity to handle this is way overkill IMHO.

Comment: Well, given the context of my program, it makes sense. The activity interacts with a sqlite database of many things, this being one of them. It is not merely for a default preference value, but goes deeper then that within the scope of my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set an `onPreferenceClickListener()` similar to the following:

xml:

```
   <Preference
        android:title="My Preferences"
        android:summary="A Preferences I am going to set"
        android:key="myPref"/>
```

code:

```
Preference myPref= (Preference) findPreference("myPref");
myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
             public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                 //LAUNCH YOUR ACTIVITY
                 return true;
             }
         });
```

Then receive the returned value in `onActivityResult()` and saved it into the preferences.

Comment: Can't quite figure out how to launch my activity from the PreferenceActivity, I am trying to create the Intent, calling the constructor, however the constructor requires an Activity context, which I do not have. Also, how would I go about saving my value into preferences?

Comment: you are unable to launch it just using `Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);`??

Comment: No. The error being: "The constructor Intent(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){}, Class<MyCalendar>) is undefined". However, I did just figure this out, I have to grab the context outside of the onPreferenceClickListener and pass it to the constructor. Thanks for the help. Do I have to use PreferenceManager to save the value of this preference? How do I go about it?

Comment: then try `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);`

Answer (score 1):

@segfault Intent i = new Intent(NameOfClass.class, MyActivity.class); this will work sure.